# Repeating String finding

Tags: python

I have having a string pattern like

```
2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 ...........
```

and i need to find out the string `2345` that is repeating .

Please note that the end of the string (i.e. the last character) may be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 .

And the string can also be

```
2 1 1 1 1 6 2 1 1 1 1 6 2 1 1 1 1 6 2 1 1 . . .
```

In this case, my answer is 2 1 1 1 6.

Any easy and fast algorithm to achieve this ?

I looked into few posts on repeating strings and found this regular expression . But its not working for all the cases.

I am looking for some algorithm (not re) to solve this.

```
import re
def findSeq(text):
    for i in range(1, len(text)/2 + 1):
        m = re.match(r'^(.{%d})\1+$'%i, text)
        if m:
            ret_num = len(m.group(1))
            return ret_num
```

Comment: For the 2nd case 2 1 1 1 6 2 1 1 1 1 6 2 1 1 1 1 6 .. isn't your answer 2 1 1 1 1 6 instead of 2 1 1 1 6.. Also can there be more than one such repeating string patterns  in this stream of numbers ?

Comment: You might want to look into suffix tree.

Comment: @skippy . It was a typo. My patter has only the repetitive numbers.

Comment: @aadarshsg , i created a suffix array . But, not sure how to implement this pattern in suffix array . Any useful link to achieve it in python.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose an algorithm like:

```
def find_pattern(text):
    candidates = []
    for i, c in enumerate(text):
        candidates = [p_l for p_l in candidates if c == text[i%p_l]]
        for p_l in candidates:
            if not ((i+1) % p_l):
                break
        else:
            candidates.append(i+1)
    return text[:candidates[0]]
```

Comment: [List slicing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(k) where k is the length of the result.  Doesn't this call `text[:i+1]` up to n times, resulting in O(n^2) complexity?  

But this is easy to fix, just keep an index instead of `pattern`.

Comment: You're right, I was talking in terms of comparisons to constrast with the (now deleted) other proposed answer. I'll update with your proposition.

Comment: The algorithm is failing for 

2212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122212221222122

Ideally, output should be 2212. But, its returning a big string

Comment: @srinath You have an extra '2' on the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, its part of the string. I mentioned it in the description . "Please note that the end of the string (i.e. the last character) may be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 ."

Comment: You're right, my original algorithm doesn't always work. Here is a newer proposition.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work too. I haven't checked this for all edge cases but for the cases you described it will work :

```
stream  = ['1' ,'1', '1', '1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6' ,'1', '1']
record = -1
same_items = -1
for k in xrange(2,len(stream)/2):
    s1 = stream[:k]
    s2 = stream[k: 2*k]
    if s1 == s2:
        #If all items are same, like 1,1,1,1,1,1,1
        if len(set(s2)) == 1:
            same_items = k
            continue
        else:
            record = k
            break

if record != -1:
    print stream[:k]
elif same_items!= -1:
    #This is when all the items in the stream are identical
    print stream[:k/2+1]
```

Output:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '6']
```

Time Complexity would be **O(N^2)**

Answer (score 0):

Does the sequence always start at the beginning of the string? If it does, here is a nice Pythonic solution:

```
def find_seq(s):
    for n in range(1, len(s)):
        if len({s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)}) == 1:
            return s[:n]
```

It works by splitting the string into groups of equal length for increasing lengths until an answer is found.

Comment: Nope. I guess I did not read your original post carefully enough. I will have a think about whether there is a way to add that functionality to my solution.